# What to revise to make it implement modularization using methods

Tags: java, methods

I already have these 3 codes made but our prof said to revise it again using methods now. Can you help or can you show me what to revise in each code?
1.)

```java
public class HeadsOrTails {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Heads = 0;
        int Tails = 0;
        
        for(long simulation = 1; simulation <= 2000000; simulation += 1)
        {
            int FlipResult = FlipCoin();
            if(FlipResult == 1)
            {
                Heads += 1;
            }
            else if(FlipResult == 0)
            {
                Tails += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Numer of heads appeared: " + Heads);
        System.out.println("Numer of tails appeared: " + Tails);
    }
    private static int FlipCoin() 
    {
        return (int) (Math.random() + 0.5);
    }
}
```

2.)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecToHex {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a decimal number: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        int rem;
        
        String result = "";
        char 
        hex[]= {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
        while(number > 0)
        {
            rem = number % 16;
            result = hex[rem]+result;
            number = number/16;
        }
        System.out.println("Hexadecimal Number: "+result);
    }
}
```

3.)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DayOfTheWeek {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Year: (e.g., 2012): ");
        int year = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Month: 1-12: ");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the Day of the month: 1-31:");
        int day = input.nextInt();
        String DayOfTheWeek = ZCAlgo(day, month, year);
        System.out.println("Day of the week is "+DayOfTheWeek);
    }

    public static String ZCAlgo(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        if (month == 1)
        {
            month = 13;
            year--;
        }
        if (month == 2)
        {
            month = 14;
            year--;
        }
        int q = day;
        int m = month;
        int k = year % 100;
        int j = year / 100;
        int h = q + 13*(m + 1) / 5 + k + k / 4 + j / 4 + 5 * j;
        h = h % 7;
        switch (h)
        {
            case 0: return "Saturday";
            case 1: return "Sunday";
            case 2: return "Monday";
            case 3: return "Tuesday";
            case 4: return "Wednesday";
            case 5: return "Thurday";
            case 6: return "Friday";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

3.)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DayOfTheWeek {
    /* *****************************************************************************
     METHOD NAME    : main
     DESCRIPTION    : Executes the main program to test the class 
                      DayOfTheWeek
    ********************************************************************************/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Year: (e.g., 2012): ");
        int year = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Month: 1-12: ");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the Day of the month: 1-31:");
        int day = input.nextInt();
        String DayOfTheWeek = ZCAlgo(day, month, year);
        System.out.println("Day of the week is "+DayOfTheWeek);
    }

    public static String ZCAlgo(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        if (month == 1)
        {
            month = 13;
            year--;
        }
        if (month == 2)
        {
            month = 14;
            year--;
        }
        int q = day;
        int m = month;
        int k = year % 100;
        int j = year / 100;
        int h = q + 13*(m + 1) / 5 + k + k / 4 + j / 4 + 5 * j;
        h = h % 7;
        switch (h)
        {
            case 0: return "Saturday";
            case 1: return "Sunday";
            case 2: return "Monday";
            case 3: return "Tuesday";
            case 4: return "Wednesday";
            case 5: return "Thurday";
            case 6: return "Friday";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your professor wants you to avoid typing duplicate code. They want you to minimize the amount of code you have to repeatedly type. For example, look at the `main` method from your `DayOfTheWeek` class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Year: (e.g., 2012): ");
    int year = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Month: 1-12: ");
    int month = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the Day of the month: 1-31:");
    int day = input.nextInt();
    //After this is more code below that we don't care about for now
}
```

You had to do 3 `System.out.print()` calls. You also did 3 `input.nextInt()` calls. That's 6 calls total.

Notice how there is a `System.out.print()` call, and then a `input.nextInt()` call immediately after? We can slim that down to something like this.

```
public static int fetchInput(Scanner input, String message) {
    System.out.print(message);
    return input.nextInt();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int year = fetchInput(input, "Enter Year: (e.g., 2012): ");
    int month = fetchInput(input, "Enter Month: 1-12: ");
    int day = fetchInput(input, "Enter the Day of the month: 1-31:");
    //After this is more code below that we don't care about for now
}
```

Now, we only have to type `fetchInput()` 3 times, which has a call to both `System.out.print()` and `input.nextInt()`, giving us a total of 5 calls.

So, 5 is less than 6, which means we have made progress towards our goal, but since it is only one less call, it may not seem significant. But in reality, there's a lot more repeats in your code - I just handed you one of them. On top of that, your professor is teaching you good habits that will help you if you ever become a programmer. What if instead of fetching 3 things, you needed to fetch 20? This is common in the real world, by the way. Using your old style, you would have had to type 20 `System.out.print()` and 20 `input.nextInt()` calls at least, putting you at around 40 calls. But doing it this new way, you would only need to type 20 `fetchInput()` calls, which has a `System.out.print()` call and an `input.nextInt()` call within it, putting our total at 22 calls for the new method. 40 vs 22 things to type is an easier to see example of how writing code that minimizes retyping the same thing saves you time.